# Audacity: stop playing and move cursor to playhead?

Tags: cursor, audacity, pause

While playing a track, I want to be able to press a button and stop what I'm listening to and move the cursor forward to that location (essentially more like pausing than stopping). But even `pause` does not move the cursor so it isn't the correct option.  `Stop` goes back to the cursor position.

Answer (score 5):

Via settings <kbd>Ctrl + P</kbd>: I found that <kbd>x</kbd> accomplishes this.

Comment: See [Audacity Manual > Playback](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/playback.html).